# Pandas combines empty rows in Excel file to a single row in dataframe

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have different excel files that I am processing with Pandas. I need to remove a certain number of rows from the top of each file. These extra rows could be empty or they could contain text. Pandas is combining some of the rows so I am not sure how many need to be removed. For example:

Here is an example excel file (represented as csv):

```
,,
,,
some text,,
,,
,,
,,
name, date, task
Jason,1-Jan,swim 
Aem,2-Jan,workout
```

Here is my current python script:

```
import pandas as pd 
xl = pd.ExcelFile('extra_rows.xlsx') 
dfs = xl.parse(xl.sheet_names[0]) 
print ("dfs: ", dfs)
```

Here is the results when I print the dataframe:

```
dfs:          Unnamed: 0           Unnamed: 1 Unnamed: 2
0  some other text                  NaN        NaN
1              NaN                  NaN        NaN
2              NaN                  NaN        NaN
3              NaN                  NaN        NaN
4             name                 date       task
5            Jason  2016-01-01 00:00:00       swim
6              Aem  2016-01-02 00:00:00    workout
```

From the file, I would remove the first 6 rows. However, from the dataframe I would only remove 4. Is there a way to read in the Excel file with the data in its raw state so the number of rows remains consistent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used `python3` and `pandas-0.18.1`. The Excel load function is `pandas.read_csv`. You can try set the parameter `header=None` to achieve. Here are sample codes:

(1) With default parameters, result will ignore leading blank lines:

```
In [12]: pd.read_excel('test.xlsx')
Out[12]: 
  Unnamed: 0 Unnamed: 1 Unnamed: 2
0      text1        NaN        NaN
1        NaN        NaN        NaN
2         n1         t2         c3
3        NaN        NaN        NaN
4        NaN        NaN        NaN
5        jim        sum        tim
```

(2) With `header=None`, result will keep leading blank lines.

```
In [13]: pd.read_excel('test.xlsx', header=None)
Out[13]: 
       0    1    2
0    NaN  NaN  NaN
1    NaN  NaN  NaN
2  text1  NaN  NaN
3    NaN  NaN  NaN
4     n1   t2   c3
5    NaN  NaN  NaN
6    NaN  NaN  NaN
7    jim  sum  tim
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is what you are looking for:

```
import pandas as pd 
xl = pd.ExcelFile('extra_rows.xlsx') 
dfs = xl.parse(skiprows=6) 
print ("dfs: ", dfs)
```

Check [the docs on ExcelFile](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.ExcelFile.parse.html) for more details.

Answer (score 2):

If you read your file in with `pd.read_excel` and pass `header=None`, the blank rows should be included:

```
In [286]: df = pd.read_excel("test.xlsx", header=None)

In [287]: df
Out[287]:
           0     1      2
0        NaN   NaN    NaN
1        NaN   NaN    NaN
2  something   NaN    NaN
3        NaN   NaN    NaN
4       name  date  other
5          1     2      3
```